# Get MyTableViewCell from method 'viewDidLoad' in MyTableViewController?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to change the text of the `UILabel` in myCustomCell at method `viewDidLoad()` of myCustomTableViewController.m

How can I access that cell??

I know vice versa but I don't know how to from `UITableViewController` to `UITableViewCell`

Comment: Why? Change the cell when it's defined / created / used

Comment: What you can do is, add `UILabel` to all the cells and put a check inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` like `if(indexPath.row == your_desired_index) { your_label.text == @"custom_text"; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at UITableView's data source functions, there is `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, this creates cells for your tableview, change your label there.

The way you want it is weird, you would have to create a cell, change its label but still return it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, which seems kinda useless.

Answer (score 1):

if you use static cells, you can get the tableViewCell by a IBOutlet link.

or for already create cell, you can get by tableview's method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`